# Custom attribute for Visualforce component that accepts SObject fields?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

Is it possible to create a custom Visualforce component that accepts an SObject field as an attribute? Basically, I want to replicate what's done with something like ...

```
<apex:inputText value="{!record.Name}"/>
```

... so that I can have a custom component that can be used as ...

```
<c:inputSpecialText value="{!record.Name}"/>
```

In this case, how should I define the attribute in my custom component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a component that takes three attributes

<c:FranchisorInvoiceFooter DDebit="{!directdebit}" Invoice="{!inv}" BillingCountry="{!client.BillingCountry}"/>

where client.BillingCountry is a sObject Field

The attribute definition for this is

<apex:attribute name="BillingCountry" description="billing Country" assignTo="{!country}" type="String" required="false"/>